# Does the wine cup have to overflow on motzai Yom Kippur

Tags: havdalah

Shmiras Shabbos k'Hilchaso rules that on Motzai Yom Tov one doesn't have to have the havdalah wine cup overflow.  Would the same be true of Yom Kippur?

Comment: Why might YK be different?

Comment: An overflowing cup of wine brings blessing to the house. If I remember correctly, the Talmud in Shabbat made no distinction between shabbat and yamim tovim or yom kippur.

Comment: The overflowing cup of wine is a minhag. I've heard that it symbolizes plentitude, i.e., that we place our faith in G-d to bless us with enough food and parnassa for the **upcoming week**. I stress the bolded part, b/c based on that assumption, it would be unnecessary to do this at any havdallah other than on M. Shabbat.